# a list of dynamic functions and dynamically calling them

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic

I would like to be able to store various static methods in a List and later look them up and dynamically call them.

Each of the static methods has different numbers of args, types and return values

```
static int X(int,int)....
static string Y(int,int,string)
```

I'd like to have a List that I can add them all to:

```
List<dynamic> list

list.Add(X);
list.Add(Y);
```

and later:

```
dynamic result = list[0](1,2);
dynamic result2 = list[1](5,10,"hello")
```

How to do this in C# 4?

Comment: +1, a different type of question.

Comment: What you're looking for is the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Google that along with `c#` and you should be set.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a list of delegate-instances, using an appropriate delegate-type for each method.

```
var list = new List<dynamic>
          {
               new Func<int, int, int> (X),
               new Func<int, int, string, string> (Y)
          };

dynamic result = list[0](1, 2); // like X(1, 2)
dynamic result2 = list[1](5, 10, "hello") // like Y(5, 10, "hello")
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need the power of `dynamic` here, you can do with simple `List<object>`:

```
class Program
{
    static int f(int x) { return x + 1; }
    static void g(int x, int y) { Console.WriteLine("hallo"); }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> l = new List<object>();
        l.Add((Func<int, int>)f);
        l.Add((Action<int, int>)g);
        int r = ((Func<int, int>)l[0])(5);
        ((Action<int, int>)l[1])(0, 0);
    }
}
```

(well, you need a cast, but you need to somehow know the signature of each of the stored methods anyway)

Answer (score 3):

```
    List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
        Action<int, int> myFunc = (int x, int y) => Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", x, y);
        Action<int, int> myFunc2 = (int x, int y) => Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", x, y);
        list.Add(myFunc);
        list.Add(myFunc2);

        (list[0])(5, 6);
```